# Instantiate struct located within a module and with all fields private

Tags: rust

I have two files:

```
.
├── my_struct.rs
└── mod.rs
```

In `my_struct` I have a struct `MyStruct` where all fields are private, and a method to manipulate them:

```rust
// my_struct.rs
pub struct MyStruct {
  private_field_1: Option<i32>,
  private_field_2: Option<i32>,
}

impl MyStruct {
  pub fn get_private_field_1(&mut self) -> Option<i32> {
    let private_field_1 = self.private_field_1;
    match private_field_1 {
      Some(value) => Some(value),
      None => None,
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Now, on `mod` file I import `my_struct`, and I want to instantiate `MyStruct`:

```rust
// mod.rs
mod my_struct;
use my_struct::MyStruct;

pub fn run() {
  let my_struct_instance = MyStruct {};
}
```

But it returns an error due to inaccesible fields.

How do I instantiate it?

Comment: Add a public function to your `impl MyStruct` for constructing it

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Will add an example

Answer (score 1):

As @vallentin said, the proper way is adding a method to construct the struct:

```rust
// my_struct.rs
pub struct MyStruct {
  private_field_1: Option<i32>,
  private_field_2: Option<i32>,
}

impl MyStruct {
  pub fn new() -> MyStruct {
    MyStruct {
      private_field_1: None,
      private_field_2: None,
    }
  }

  pub fn get_private_field_1(&mut self) -> Option<i32> {
    let private_field_1 = self.private_field_1;
    match private_field_1 {
      Some(value) => Some(value),
      None => None,
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

```
// mod.rs
mod my_struct;
use my_struct::MyStruct;

pub fn run() {
  let my_struct_instance = MyStruct::new()
}
```

Comment: Note also that, if you have a constructor method without parameters, it's idiomatic to implement (or, in this case, derive) the trait `Default`.